# How to seed a JPA application with mutliple repository using bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm new to spring boot and I'm trying to populate my MySQL database trought JPA and hibernate using a bean in my application class, and I can't seem to be able to seed more than one repository at once... Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here, I tryed to find an answer, but I probably don't have the right lexicon, I could not find anything.

Here's my application class

```java
package co.ligneauto.webapplication;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import co.ligneauto.webapplication.dataaccesslayer.CoordinatesRepository;
import co.ligneauto.webapplication.dataaccesslayer.CustomerRepository;
import co.ligneauto.webapplication.dataaccesslayer.TravelRepository;
import co.ligneauto.webapplication.models.Customer;
import co.ligneauto.webapplication.models.TravelCoordinates;
import co.ligneauto.webapplication.models.Travel;

import java.util.HashSet;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LigneautoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LigneautoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    // This works if I only have the Customer repository
    public CommandLineRunner SeedCustomers(CustomerRepository customerRepository, CoordinatesRepository coordinatesRepository, TravelRepository travelRepository) { 
        return (args) -> {
            // save a few customers
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Kim", "Bauer"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("David", "Palmer"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Michelle", "Dessler"));
            coordinatesRepository.save(new TravelCoordinates("45.2665", "72.1480"));
            coordinatesRepository.save(new TravelCoordinates("45.5750", "72.5261"));

            Iterable<TravelCoordinates> coordinates = coordinatesRepository.findAll();

            HashSet<TravelCoordinates> coordinatesSet = new HashSet<TravelCoordinates>();

            for (TravelCoordinates item : coordinates) {
                coordinatesSet.add(item);
            }

            Travel travel = new Travel("Roxton Falls -> Magog", coordinatesSet);

            travelRepository.save(travel);
        };
    }
}
```

If you guys are looking for the complete project, it's available here on gitlab
https://gitlab.com/MathieuAuclair/springbootintroduction

#### Edit

as requested, here the error I'm getting trying to run the application

```sh
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Stacktrace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-19 10:48:04.374 ERROR 17768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [travel_coordinates] encountered more than once
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at co.ligneauto.webapplication.LigneautoApplication.main(LigneautoApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [travel_coordinates] encountered more than once
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [travel_coordinates] encountered more than once
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.checkExportIdentifier(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:487) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
        ... 26 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.100 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-19T10:48:04-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu, the Spring Boot way is much simpler. Just add in `src/main/resources` a `schema.sql` and `data.sql` and Spring Boot will automatically execute the scripts if you have your database configured via application properties.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will try that, but I would like to understand how to do it using the bean too if you can explain it to me, I would be really greatful!

Comment: @Qualifier , possibly this you need look at this article https://dzone.com/articles/spring-configuration-and

Comment: That doesn't explain much... what should I understand from that? I'm use to dotnet core where if you want to get injected dependency, you simply add them as a parameter on a controller constructor, what's the equivalent of that in java where I can fetch an injected repository service?

Comment: I don't know what's the issue but I changed some of your JPA mapping and it is working fine.
in Travel; `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "travel") private Set<TravelCoordinates> coordinates;` and in TravelCoordinates; `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name= "travel_id") private Travel travel;`

Comment: The code that you posted looks fine in that regard. You should specify "doesn't work" a bit more in detail. What does that mean? Do you get an exception? Which one? If not, what log entries do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking your JPA mapping should do the trick

In Travel.java

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "travel") 
private Set<TravelCoordinates> coordinates;
```

In TravelCoordinates.java

```java
@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn(name= "travel_id") 
private Travel travel;
```

Tested with H2 in-mem db instead of your mysql

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:lignecar
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: I still get an error when running, were you able to do ```./mvnw spring-boot:run``` without exceptions? It probably on my side, but you cloned the repo changed that and it was running?

Comment: @MathieuAuclair I was. I did use a clean H2 in-mem database instead of a mysql one

Comment: I'll accept your answer, can you send me a pull request to my repository please? :)

Comment: lol. Sure, I can do that :) Mmm need username/password apparently

Comment: Do you have a gitlab account? You should be able to do it using your credentials

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not

Comment: @MathieuAuclair I hosted it myself [on github](https://github.com/nicovanbelle/ligneauto)